# Using object path in $lookup mongo aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

For today's task I am trying aggregating documents in a collection (let's call it `collection1` and in one of the pipeline's stages I am trying to use $lookup to retrieve documents from another collection (let's call it `collection2`).

`collection1` object model:

```
{
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2"
    "field3": "value3"
}
```

`collection2` object model:

```
{
    "field1: "value1",
    "field2"; "value2",
    "field3: {
        "field31": "value31",
        "field32": "value32"
    }
}
```

What I am exactly trying to do is to retrieve the documents from `collection2` where `field3.field31` equals value of the `collection1`s `field1`.

My $lookup stage looks like approx like this but currently it doesn't seem to work. I did not find any clue if this should work but looking forward to your replies.

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "collection2",
        let: {
            "c": "$field1",
            "l": "$field2",
            "t": "$field3",
        },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $and: [
                            { $eq: ["$field1", "$$c"] },
                            { $eq: ["$field2", "$$l"] },
                            { $eq: ["$field3.field31", "$$t"] },
                        ]
                    }
                },
            },
        ],
        as: "awesomejoin"
    }
}
```

I want to avoid having a project or a group and then unwinding and filtering again. My wish is to get the records directly from the match stage thinking this is better in terms of performance...

Let me know your thoughts on this.

Thank you

Comment: Values does not match `field3.field31` and `field3` https://mongoplayground.net/p/eF9Oz30NklL

Comment: Thank you for the effort & time invested here. I could not share the actual objects and the full pipeline but of course i could have provided better examples. My issue was that for the "as" i seemed to be using a mongo reserve keyword. `scheduled`. Changed the name and everything came alive. Too many hours worked yesterday.

Comment: Sorry but not able to get you. Please try to explain with some examples and sample collections

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
db.Collection1.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "Collection2",
         localField: "field1",
         foreignField: "field3.field31",
         as: "docs"
       }
  }
])
```

It should be simple with plain `$lookup`, not exactly sure why you're creating local variables and looking for equals on same variables, Also `$unwind` will be used on arrays, over objects you could access inner elements using `.` notation same as like in programming languages.

**Ref :** [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#examples)

Comment: I exemplified with same value fielda for the sake of example. I acctually need the complex lookul pipeline to join by matching multiple fields:). Not only the one which causes problems

Comment: @AndreiTerecoasa : Don't you need to do this : `{ $eq: ["$field3.field31", "$$c"] }` ? rather than { $eq: ["$field3.field31", "$$t"] } !! Seems like you're checking for `field3.field31== field3` but what you need is `field3.field31== field1`

Comment: my mistake that i used so cryptic names for the fields but it doesn't really matter. it can be either but what doesn't work for me is `{ $eq: ["$field3.field31", "$$t"] }`. I think it's because of the `"$field3.field32"` but i cannot make sense of it

Comment: @AndreiTerecoasa : I'm sorry but It's very confusing by the way you're presenting it !! So if you can give actual sample data + req o/p + your query it would very easy, An equals should work over there but did you check data type of `field3.field31` does match with either `field1` or `field3` of collection1 ??

Comment: Thank you for the effort & time invested here. I could not share the actual objects and the full pipeline but of course i could have provided better examples. My issue was that for the "as" i seemed to be using a mongo reserve keyword. `scheduled`. Changed the name and everything came alive. Too many hours worked yesterday.